# How to make device mappings stay after reboot?

Tags: linux, udev, dm-crypt, device-mapper

I notice that if a device mapping is created with the low-level **dmsetup** or through ioctls, the device mapping will no longer be there after reboot.

1. Is this normal? I am using a USB to test out dm_crypt
2. If it is normal, how do I go about making the mapping stay around? Do I need to look into udev?

Thanks!

---

*Edit for clarification*

What I mean by device mapping is the table entry that specifies how to map each range of physical block sectors to a virtual block device. You can see what I mean, if using LVM, with the **dmsetup table** command. This will dump all current device table mappings. Here's an example for the device mapping *linear* target, tying two disks together into a LVM swap (physical block abstraction):

```
vg00-lv_swap: 0 1028160 linear /dev/sdb 0
vg00-lv_swap: 1028160 3903762 linear /dev/sdc 0
```

The format here is:

```
<mapping_name>: <start_block> <segment_length> <mapping_target> <block_device> <offset>
```

Where:

- **mapping_name:** the name of the *virtual* device
- **start_block:** starting block for *virtual* device
- **segment_length:** length in sectors (512 byte chunks)
- **mapping_target:** device mapping target such as *linear*, *crypt*, or *striped*
- **block_device:** which physical block device to use, in this case defined by major:minor
- **offset:** offset on *physical* block device

My problem is that, after creating a new entry in the device mapping table, it disappears after boot. That is, running something like:

```
dmsetup create TestEncrypted --table "0 $(blockdev --getsz /dev/sdb) crypt serpent-cbc-essiv:sha256 a7f67ad...ee 0 /dev/sdb 0"
```

and then rebooting causes the mapping table entry to disappear (i.e. doesn't show up with **dmsetup table**), as well as the corresponding `/dev/mapper/TestEncrypted`

Comment: Don't know but for discs UUID works. Hope that gives you a lead.  I am not familiar with other device mapping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not 100% I understand what you mean by mapping but, Yes this seems normal.  You need to add the device to either /etc/crypttab or /etc/fstab like you would to mount any other drive.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/System_configuration#crypttab

^ Should have the information you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation! Idk how I missed this when googling myself. I'll give it a read and see if it can address my problems. I also edited my post for clarity.